# Matplotlib shows x-axis labels incomplete ; how to prevent overlapping?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've written the code for showing MACD indicator graph. what I did is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv(#stock_chart)
df = df.rename(columns={"<DTYYYYMMDD>":"Date"})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format="%Y%m%d")
print(df.head())
#seting index for graph
df = df.set_index(df['Date'].values)
print(df.head())
```

*which my dataframe's head is* :
[image: Graph columns and rows!]

```
#Macd
S_term = 12
L_term = 26
s_ema = df.close.ewm(span=S_term, adjust=False).mean()
l_ema = df.close.ewm(span=L_term, adjust=False).mean()
#calculate MACD
macd = s_ema - l_ema

signal_term = 9
signal_line = macd.ewm(span= signal_term, adjust=False).mean()

#plot the graphs
plt.figure(figsize=(100,10)) #width = 12.2in, height = 4.5
plt.plot(df.index, macd, label='macd', color = 'red')
plt.plot(df.index, signal_line, label='Signal Line', color='blue')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

finally , I got to this :

[image: Matplotlib's graph]

Anyway , the problem is that despite row index labels are like this : `2020-08-19 or "%Y%m%d"` , graph labels are incomplete and if I reorder it , the data overlaps on each other . what do I have to do ?

Comment: What do you mean by incomplete?

Comment: I mean it has to show sth like this in x-axis === 2004-10-25 but it just presents 2004 ... okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Date locators](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers) and [Date formatters](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html#date-formatters).

```py
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas

N = 192
numpy.random.seed(N)

dates = pandas.date_range('1/1/2004', periods=N, freq='m')

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data=numpy.random.randn(N), 
    index=dates,
    columns=['A']
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.index, df['A'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]

*interval* is the interval between each iteration. For example, if `interval=2`, mark every second occurrence.

```py
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas

N = 192
numpy.random.seed(N)

dates = pandas.date_range('1/1/2004', periods=N, freq='m')

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data=numpy.random.randn(N), 
    index=dates,
    columns=['A']
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.index, df['A'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))


fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I wanted to do , I wanna find a way to show x-axis labels completely ... thanks!

Comment: @Dave3652 If you really want to show labels completely, only use `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))`. But that will cause unavoidable ticks overlap. And there is no easy to fix it. I offer you an example how to show months intervally.